# How to get an array of files in a directory

Tags: arrays, node.js, file, directory

In PHP I have the following code to create an array of all images in a directory.

```
$dir    = '/public/images/';
$files = scandir($dir);
```

What would the NodeJS equivalent be?

I am looking to create an array of all images in a directory.

Using this in Laravel webpack mix in development so it would run either on the local machine or on the server itself by command line.

Instead of the following as there is an unknown number of images in the directory and what the name would be.

```
if (mix.config.inProduction) {
    mix.version(['public/images/50x50-1.png', 'public/images/50x50-1.svg'])
}
```

Desired Code:

```
if (mix.config.inProduction) {
    var imagesArray = // get the list here
    mix.version(imagesArray)
}
```

Comment: Are you running Javascript on the client or server? Javascript in browsers can't access directories.

Comment: Using this in larval webpack mix in development so it would run either on the local machine or on the server itself by command line.

Comment: Do you mean Laravel?

Comment: yep I meant Laravel

Comment: I tagged the question NodeJS because this is likely irrelevant to browser JavaScript. Please review the changes and edit any additional details I might have removed or changed incorrectly.

Comment: I suppose are correct Emile. Thank you

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If this is running on the server, you should have access to node's `fs` module.

```
const testFolder = '/public/images/';
const fs = require('fs');
fs.readdir(testFolder, (err, files) => {
  files.forEach(file => {
    console.log(file);
  });
})
```

You can read up on fs [here](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html)

Comment: Thank you jas7457.  I will look into fs.  I only know the basic syntax of javascript at this time

Comment: Well this has answered my question although not provided a complete solution. Thanks

Comment: Why is this not a complete solution? fs.readdir is asynchronous, so if you're trying to use it in code, you couldn't until the callback executes. You could change it to `var imagesArray = fs.readdirSync(testFolder)` to synchronously read in the files, and that may be more what you're looking for.